# SQL: Find Items based on their attributes

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

On PostgreSQL, I have a table item, and a table item_attribute. So an item can have multiple attributes.

table: item

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

table: item_attribute

| id | item_id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | foo | bar |
| 2 | 1 | size | M |
| 3 | 1 | country | DE |
| 4 | 2 | foo | baz |
| 5 | 2 | size | M |
| 6 | 2 | country | DE |
| 7 | 3 | other | test |
| 8 | 3 | size | M |
| 9 | 3 | country | EN |

Now, I need to find items that match a given set of attribute name/value pairs

So, let's say I want to find items with attributes of `country` with value `DE` and `size` with value `M` the result set should be

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

if I want to find items with attributes of `country` with value `EN` and `size` with value `M` the result set should be

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | C |

Any hints here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an aggregation approach we can try:

```sql
SELECT i.id, i.name
FROM item i
INNER JOIN item_attribute ia
    ON ia.item_id = i.id
GROUP BY i.id, i.name
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ia.name = 'country' AND ia.value = 'DE') > 0 AND
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ia.name = 'size' AND ia.value = 'M') > 0;
```

The above uses conditional aggregation to find items from Germnay in medium size.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to aggregate the attributes into a JSON value and use the quite powerful [JSON operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to find the items

```
select itm.*
from item itm
where exists (select null
              from item_attribute att
              where att.item_id = itm.id
              group by item_id
              having jsonb_object_agg(name, value) @> '{"country": "DE", "size": "M"}'
              )
```

I am not not sure if this is faster or slower than the traditional approach with counting (see Tim Biegeleisen's answer). It is a bit more flexible though.

Depending on the data distribution, doing the aggregation once for all items might be faster:

```
select itm.*
from item itm
  join (
    select item_id, jsonb_object_agg(name, value) as attributes
    from item_attribute att
    group by item_id
    having jsonb_object_agg(name, value) @> '{"country": "DE", "size": "M"}'
  ) atr on atr.item_id = itm.id
```

This also enables to display all attributes (as JSON) in a column of the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the intersection between all "*item_id*"s that satisfy your conditions inside the "*item_attribute*" table, then match the corresponding value inside the "*item*" table.

```
WITH filtered_ids AS (
    SELECT item_id FROM item_attribute WHERE name  = 'country' AND value = 'DE'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT item_id FROM item_attribute WHERE name  = 'size'    AND value = 'M'
)
SELECT * 
FROM item
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM filtered_ids)
```

You can stack as many conditions as you want inside the "*filtered_ids*" cte.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q9BBEF4N3cm4n1JfCewJxv/0).